# Python module for statically typed class attributes

Tags: python, static-typing

I want my Python class to automatically check the type of value when assigning it to an attribute.

There is enthought's [traits](http://code.enthought.com/projects/traits/) module and IPython has a pure python version as its sub module [IPython.utils.traitlets](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/dev/api/generated/IPython.utils.traitlets.html).  Are there any similar modules?  If that module has automatic command line argument parser to set these attribute, that would be better.

**EDIT**: Thanks for the snippets. But I want Python **library**. If there exists library to do that, I don't want to reimplement by myself.

Comment: Why would you want statically typed variables for a dynamically typed language?

Comment: Define automatically check. You can always comapre the type.

Comment: If you care about static typing, you're using the wrong language.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about `traits` ... but if you want to check the type of an object when it is assigned, you can override `__setattr__` to check that...

```
class MyClass(object):
   def __setattr__(self, attr, val):
       if attr == 'my_attr':
           if not isinstance(val, str):
              raise ValueError('my_attr must be a string!')
           else:
              object.__setattr__(self, attr, val)
       else:
           object.__setattr__(self, attr, val)

a = MyClass()
a.my_attr = "Hello World!"  # This is OK
a.my_attr = 1               # This is not: ValueError
```

But I really wouldn't recommend doing this without a really good reason ...

Answer (score 1):

almost any manner of "automatic" behavior can be determined on object attributes using python descriptors.  The simplest sort of descriptor is `property`:

```
class Foo(object):
    @property
    def bar(self):
        try:
            return self._bar
        except AttributeError:
            return "default value"

    @bar.setter
    def bar(self, value):
        if isinstance(value, Baz): # for some other type "Baz"
            self._bar = value
        else:
            raise ValueError("wrong type for attribute bar,"
                             " expected %r, got %r" % (Baz, type(value))
```

Comment: I just came across this again and thought to myself "That's the perfect place for `property`".  I was going to add it to my answer, but it turns out you've already done it.  +1